Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'
In my Flutter app, I am using below package :
popover: ^0.2.6+2

While Running the app, Getting below error:

../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/popover-0.2.8+2/lib/src/popover_item.dart:137:25:
Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class
'BuildContext'.

'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
a getter or field named 'mounted'.
if (!widget.context.mounted) return;
^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: Script '/Users/growexxlt235/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
line: 1159

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildStagDebug'.



Process 'command '/Users/growexxlt235/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with
non-zero exit value 1


What might be the issue?
